# Filtering on CTEs in SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I am trying to write a ؤiew where I can define variables. One of them is the "StateCd" variable. further in my query I need to filter down to the state I define in the variables and all the other state I define in the second `WITH` statement. how can I write a code which selects all the states in the second `WITH` statement except the state I define in "StateCd"

```
WITH MyVars (StateCd, DateDay, CompanyCd, LineCd) AS 
( 
    SELECT
        'SD' AS StateCd,
        '2017-11-30' AS IssueDate,
        '010' AS CompanyCd,
        '010' AS LineCd
), MyStates (CO, IA, KS, MO, MT, NE, ND, SD, WY) AS 
( 
    SELECT
        'CO' AS CO,
        'IA' AS IA,
        'KS' AS KS,
        'MO' AS MO,
        'MT' AS MT,
        'NE' AS NE,
        'ND' AS ND,
        'SD' AS SD,
        'WY' AS WY
)
```

Comment: Are you implying you're trying to pass a value to a `VIEW`? That's not how a `VIEW` works; they're effectively a virtual table, which is defined by your query. They aren't parametrised, and don't accept variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your list of states should really be data instead of schema, which means you should structure your second CTE differently.  Then use an OUTER JOIN.

```
WITH MyVars (StateCd, DateDay, CompanyCd, LineCd)
    AS ( 
        SELECT
            'SD'            AS StateCd,
            '2017-11-30'    AS IssueDate,
            '010'           AS CompanyCd,
            '010'           AS LineCd
        ),
    MyStates ([State])
    AS ( 
        SELECT 'CO' AS [State] UNION
        SELECT 'IA' UNION
        SELECT 'KS' UNION
        SELECT 'MO' UNION
        SELECT 'MT' UNION
        SELECT 'NE' UNION
        SELECT 'ND' UNION
        SELECT 'SD' UNION
        SELECT 'WY'
        )
SELECT MyStates.[State]
FROM MyStates
LEFT JOIN MyVars ON MyVars.StateCd = MyStates.[State]
WHERE MyVars.StateCd IS NULL;
```